# I have a piece of code written in fortran 90 output is different when I compile it different times

Tags: fortran, gfortran, gsl, fgsl

I use the same compiler (gfortran) and computer every time I compile it and I don't change the source code, but on different compilations it gives a completely different outcome. Sometimes a reasonable outcome and sometimes a wrong outcome.

For instance I compiled it and got the next very unreasonable outputs.

0.0000000000000000      ,   3.0902604013843218E+049 ,   3.0902604013843218E+049 ,   3.0902604013843218E+049 ,   5.3524880238158376E+049

2.0000000000000000      ,  -6.1610238730665058E+049 ,  -6.1610238730665058E+049 ,  -6.1610238730665058E+049 ,   1.0671206374795975E+050

4.0000000000000000      ,   5.5751160679618236E+049 ,   5.5751160679618236E+049 ,   5.5751160679618236E+049 ,   9.6563842878035016E+049

6.0000000000000000      ,  -1.0179425493222214E+049 ,  -1.0179425493222214E+049 ,  -1.0179425493222214E+049 ,   1.7631282146122754E+049

8.0000000000000000      ,   2.4002992709421553E+049 ,   2.4002992709421553E+049 ,   2.4002992709421553E+049 ,   4.1574402906423475E+049

10.000000000000000      ,   3.5499818567499908E+049 ,   3.5499818567499908E+049 ,   3.5499818567499908E+049 ,   6.1487489418386840E+049

12.000000000000000      ,  -3.5465339877133604E+049 ,  -3.5465339877133604E+049 ,  -3.5465339877133604E+049 ,   6.1427770574893967E+049

14.000000000000000      ,   3.7523505062483277E+049 ,   3.7523505062483277E+049 ,   3.7523505062483277E+049 ,   6.4992617246289011E+049

Then without changing anything I recompiled the same code and ran it again and got the more reasonable first result:

0.0000000000000000      , -0.20075827532679802      ,   5.7540609466025759E-003 ,  0.33972754855979093      ,  0.39465402770022856

Why does this happen? Is it a problem in my code or the compiler. I leave the code just in case its useful to answer the question. I'm just starting to learn fortran, and sorry for the comments in spanish.

EDIT: In this program I use fgsl, a fortran interface to the gnu scientific library, it can be found here: https://github.com/reinh-bader/fgsl

```
program trace_of_product
        use fgsl
        implicit none
        real(fgsl_double) :: p1, p2, p3, t, r, omega, tmax, rad, zav, yav, xav, integ1, integ2, integ3
        integer(fgsl_int) :: i, j, k, nin, nt, jmax
        complex(fgsl_double) :: wigner_func, z_sym, y_sym, x_sym
        real(fgsl_double), parameter :: pi = 3.14159265359
        character(len=3) :: filenumber

        omega = 0.01
        nin  = 500
        nt   = 50
        jmax = 9
        tmax = 100
        r = sqrt(1.0d0*jmax)

        write(filenumber, '(I0.3)') jmax

        open(unit = 1, file = 'data'//trim(filenumber)//'.csv')

        do k = 0,nt
                t = k*tmax/nt
                zav = 0.0d0
                yav = 0.0d0
                xav = 0.0d0
                do j = 1,jmax,2
                        integ1 = 0.0d0
                        integ2 = 0.0d0
                        integ3 = 0.0d0

                        !
                        ! Esta parte del código calcula la integral del producto de la
                        ! j-función de Wigner y el j-simbolo de los operadores de posición en la región
                        ! [0,2pi)x[0,pi)x[0,4pi) y dV = sin(theta) d(phi) d(theta) d(psi)
                        !

                        do i = 0,nin
                                p1 = 2*pi*rand()
                                p2 = pi*rand()
                                p3 = 4*pi*rand()
                
                                integ1 = integ1 + realpart(wigner_func(j,r,t,omega,p1,p2,p3))*realpart(z_sym(j,t,omega,p1,p2,p3))&
                                         *sin(p2)
                                integ2 = integ2 + realpart(wigner_func(j,r,t,omega,p1,p2,p3))*realpart(y_sym(j,t,omega,p1,p2,p3))&
                                         *sin(p2)
                                integ3 = integ3 + realpart(wigner_func(j,r,t,omega,p1,p2,p3))*realpart(x_sym(j,t,omega,p1,p2,p3))&
                                         *sin(p2)
                        end do
                        integ1 = integ1*pi*(j+1)/nin
                        integ2 = integ2*pi*(j+1)/nin
                        integ3 = integ3*pi*(j+1)/nin
                        zav = zav +integ1
                        yav = yav +integ2
                        xav = xav +integ3
                        
                end do
                rad = sqrt(xav**2+yav**2+zav**2)
                write(1,*) t,',',xav,',',yav,',',zav,',',rad    
                write(*,*) t,',',xav,',',yav,',',zav,',',rad
        end do 
end program


!
! Esta función calcula la j-función de Wigner para un estado coherente de dos
! modos |ab>=|a>|b>, rho = |ab><ab|. N y J están restingidos a que N+J=j 
!

function wigner_func(jc,r,t,omega,phi,theta,psi) result(Wp)
        use fgsl
        implicit none
        real(fgsl_double), intent(in) :: r, t, omega, phi, theta, psi
        integer(fgsl_int), intent(in) :: jc
        complex(fgsl_double) :: wigner_D, Wp
        real(fgsl_double) :: wigner_small_d, cg
        integer(fgsl_int) :: m, mp, k, l, q, N, J
        real(fgsl_double), parameter :: pi = 3.14159265359
        
        do N  = 0,jc
                J = jc-N
        do k  = abs(N-J),jc
        do m  = -J,J
        do mp = -N,N
        do l  = -k,k
        do q  = -k,k

                Wp = Wp + exp(-r**2) * r**(2*jc) * (2*k+1) * sin(pi/8)**(jc-m-mp) * cos(pi/8)**(jc+m+mp)* &
                   cg(N,mp,J,m,k,l)*wigner_D(k,l,q,phi+omega*t,theta,psi)*wigner_small_d(k,q,N-J,pi/2) / &
                   sqrt(Gamma(N-mp+1.0d0)*Gamma(J-m+1.0d0)*Gamma(N+mp+1.0d0)*Gamma(J+m+1.0d0)*(jc+1)*(2*N+1))


        end do
        end do
        end do
        end do
        end do
        end do

end function wigner_func


!
! Esta función calcula el j-simbolo del operador z, j = 2l + 1
!

function z_sym(j,t,omega,phi,theta,psi) result(Wz)
        use fgsl
        implicit none
        real(fgsl_double), intent(in) :: t, omega, phi, theta, psi
        integer(fgsl_int), intent(in) :: j
        complex(fgsl_double) :: Wigner_D, Wz
        real(fgsl_double) :: wigner_small_d, cg
        integer(fgsl_int) :: l,m,k,qp,q
        real(fgsl_double), parameter :: pi = 3.14159265359

        if ( mod(j,2) == 1 ) then
        l = (j-1)/2
        
        do m  = -l,l
        do k  = 1,j
        do qp = -k,k
        do q  = -k,k
                Wz = Wz + sqrt(((l+1.0d0)**2-m**2)/((4*(l+1)**2-1)*(j+1)))*(2*k+1)*&
                     Wigner_D(k,qp,q,phi+omega*t,theta,psi)* &
                     (cg(l+1,m,l,m,k,qp)*wigner_small_d(k,q,1,pi/2)/sqrt(j+1.0d0)+&
                     cg(l,m,l+1,m,k,qp)*wigner_small_d(k,q,-1,pi/2)/sqrt(1.0d0*j))
        
        end do
        end do
        end do
        end do

        end if

end function z_sym

!
! Esta función calcula el j-simbolo del operador y, j = 2l + 1
!

function y_sym(j,t,omega,phi,theta,psi) result(Wy)
        use fgsl
        implicit none
        real(fgsl_double), intent(in) :: t, omega, phi, theta, psi
        integer(fgsl_int), intent(in) :: j
        complex(fgsl_double) :: Wigner_D, Wy
        real(fgsl_double) :: wigner_small_d, cg
        integer(fgsl_int) :: l, m, k, s, q
        real(fgsl_double), parameter :: pi = 3.141596265359

        if ( mod(j,2) == 1 ) then 
        
        l = (j-1)/2

        do m = -l,l
        do k = 1,j
        do q = -k,k
        do s = -k,k
        
        Wy = Wy+cmplx(0,0.5)*sqrt((2*k+1)/((4*(l+1)**2-1)*(j+1.0d0)))*wigner_D(k,s,q,phi+omega*t,theta,psi)*&
             (sqrt((l+m+1)*(l+m+2.0d0))*(wigner_small_d(k,q,-1,pi/2)*cg(l,m,l+1,m+1,k,s)/sqrt(1.0d0*j)- &
             wigner_small_d(k,q,1,pi/2)*cg(l+1,m+1,l,m,k,s)/sqrt(j+2.0d0)) + sqrt((l-m)*(l-m+1.0d0))*(&
             wigner_small_d(k,q,-1,pi/2)*cg(l,m+1,l+1,m,k,s)/sqrt(1.0d0*j)-wigner_small_d(k,q,1,pi/2)*&
             cg(l+1,m,l,m+1,k,s)/sqrt(j+2.0d0)))

        end do
        end do
        end do
        end do

        end if

end function

!
! Esta función calcula el j-simbolo del operador x, j = 2l + 1
!

function x_sym(j,t,omega,phi,theta,psi) result(Wx)
        use fgsl
        implicit none
        real(fgsl_double), intent(in) :: t, omega, phi, theta, psi
        integer(fgsl_int), intent(in) :: j
        complex(fgsl_double) :: Wigner_D, Wx
        real(fgsl_double) :: wigner_small_d, cg
        integer(fgsl_int) :: l, m, k, s, q
        real(fgsl_double), parameter :: pi = 3.141596265359

        if ( mod(j,2) == 1 ) then 
        
        l = (j-1)/2

        do m = -l,l
        do k = 1,j
        do q = -k,k
        do s = -k,k
        
        Wx = Wx+0.5*sqrt((2*k+1)/((4*(l+1)**2-1)*(j+1.0d0)))*wigner_D(k,s,q,phi+omega*t,theta,psi)*&
             (-sqrt((l+m+1)*(l+m+2.0d0))*(wigner_small_d(k,q,-1,pi/2)*cg(l,m,l+1,m+1,k,s)/sqrt(1.0d0*j)+ &
             wigner_small_d(k,q,1,pi/2)*cg(l+1,m+1,l,m,k,s)/sqrt(j+2.0d0)) + sqrt((l-m)*(l-m+1.0d0))*(&
             wigner_small_d(k,q,-1,pi/2)*cg(l,m+1,l+1,m,k,s)/sqrt(1.0d0*j)+wigner_small_d(k,q,1,pi/2)*&
             cg(l+1,m,l,m+1,k,s)/sqrt(j+2.0d0)))

        end do
        end do
        end do
        end do
        
        end if

end function



!
! Esta función calcula los coeficientes de Clebsch-Gordan
!

function cg(j,m,j1,m1,j2,m2) result(cgn)
        use fgsl
        implicit none
        integer(fgsl_int), intent(in) :: j, m, j1, m1, j2, m2
        real(fgsl_double) :: cgn
        
        cgn = (-1)**(-j1+j2-m)*sqrt(2.0*j+1)*fgsl_sf_coupling_3j(2*j1,2*j2,2*j,2*m1,2*m2,-2*m)

end function cg

!
! Esta función es la d-función de Wigner
!

function wigner_small_d(j,m,mp,theta) result(d)
        use fgsl
        implicit none
        integer(fgsl_int), intent(in) :: j, m, mp
        integer(fgsl_int) :: k
        real(fgsl_double), intent(in) :: theta
        real(fgsl_double) :: d
        
        do k = max(0,m-mp),min(j-mp,j+m)
                d = d + (-1)**k * cos(theta/2)**(2*j+m-mp-2*k) * sin(theta/2)**(mp-m+2*k) / &
                    (Gamma(j-mp-k+1.0d0)*Gamma(k+1.0d0)*Gamma(mp-m+k+1.0d0)*Gamma(j+m-k+1.0d0)) 
        end do

        d = sqrt(Gamma(j+m+1.0d0)*Gamma(j-m+1.0d0)*Gamma(j+mp+1.0d0)*Gamma(j-mp+1.0d0))*d

end function wigner_small_d

!
! Esta función es la D-función de Wigner
!

function wigner_D(j,m,mp,phi,theta,psi) result(D)
        use fgsl
        implicit none
        integer(fgsl_int), intent(in) :: j, m, mp
        real(fgsl_double), intent(in) :: phi, theta, psi
        real(fgsl_double) :: wigner_small_d
        complex(fgsl_double) :: D

        D = exp(-cmplx(0,1)*phi*m)*wigner_small_d(j,m,mp,theta)*exp(-cmplx(0,1)*psi*mp)

end function wigner_D
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. In modern Fortran functioms and subroutines should be placed in modules so that the compilers can check that they are called correctly.

Comment: Put the functions into a module and re-compile.  That way the compiler can check the calls made to them.  I don't immediately see why mis-called functions would cause the problem you report, but do get the compiler to check.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code cannot be compiled because it uses a `fgsl` module.  The code for that module has not been provided.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thank you for your help. I did that and got no errors from the compiler. So far I haven't had the same error, I'll try to run and recompile the code several times without hanging the code just to make sure but it is a bit slow and my computer is also not that fast.

Answer (score -1):

Does it also happen when you run the program multiple times without recompiling it? If that is the case, you are probably reading a variable that has not been assigned yet.
When debugging a piece of fortran code it is useful to include some debug flags. I use:

```
    gfortran myprog.f90 -g -O0 -Wall -fcheck=all -fbacktrace
```

You can look them up in the gnu fortran compiler documentation if your interested in what they are doing.

Comment: No, if I run the program multiple times without recompiling the output doesn't change. I used those flags and got no warnings or errors.